# Return top element in a stack

Tags: java, indexing, methods, linked-list

I am struggling with the top() method that is supposed to retrieve the top element of the stack, or return null if this stack is empty and return the top element of the stack. How can fix the loop?

```
public class Stack<E> implements IStack<E> {
Node head;
    public E top() {

        if (head == null)
            return null;

        Node<E> tempNode = head;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (tempNode.getmNextNode() == null) {
                tempNode.getmElement();
            }
            tempNode = tempNode.getmNextNode();
        }
        return tempNode.getmElement();
    }
}
```

My Node class:

```
public class Node<E> {
    private E mElement;
    private Node<E> mNextNode;

    Node(E data) {
        this.setmElement(data);
    }

    public E getmElement() {
        return this.mElement;
    }

    public void setmElement(E element) {
        this.mElement = element;
    }

    public Node<E> getmNextNode() {
        return this.mNextNode;
    }

    public void setmNextNode(Node<E> node) {
        this.mNextNode = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what errors are you facing? and is that your full code? Where are 'head' and 'size defined?

Comment: Wouldn't `head` be the top of the stack? If not, why not? Why would you need to keep track of the bottom of the stack?

Comment: Probably should include your `push` code to give us a hint at your implementation - but most likely you just need to return `head`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public E top() {
    if (head == null)
        return null;
    Node<E> tempNode = head;
    while(tempNode.getmNextNode()!=null) {
        tempNode = tempNode.getmNextNode();
    }
    return tempNode.getmElement();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but got error Required type: E for return head.getmElement()

Comment: This should not give you such an error. There is something wrong somewhere else in your program. Post the complete code for further help.

Comment: I had to add <E> in Node<E> head; so it does not give me this error now. I guess head is the bottom of the stack though because it returns element 0

Comment: @Natalie_94 - I've just updated my answer. I hope, it works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `top()` method is supposed to return the last pushed element into the stack and not the first one. When pushing a new element, the `head` is referenced to this element. Thus, the `head` is the top element and would be then returned by your method.

```
public class Stack<E> implements IStack<E>{

    public E top() {
    if(head==null){
    throw new StackEmptyException();
     }
    return head.getmElement();
     }
}
```